# Diversos Value[] iguais de checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

Fiz uma tabela com 180 checkbox mas só 3 serão selecionados aleatoriamente pelo visitante do site. Quando clico em "Próximo" aparece tudo OK na URL da página seguinte:

`....&values[]=18&values[]=19&values[]=110`

Na página seguinte como eu faço p/ capturar esses valores e reenviar pelo formulário para voltarem a aparecer na URL?

Li uma pergunta aqui do site que seria isso aqui mas não sei se está certo ou se coloquei no lugar certo pois nada mudou.

`if( !empty( $_GET['values'] ) ) {
    foreach( $_GET['values'] as $key => $value ) {
        echo "<br />Semana $key<br />";
        foreach( $value as $values ) {
            echo "$values<br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>`

Answer (score 1):

## Identificando e resolvendo problemas

Você está passando os dados via GET, com input com o mesmo nome, mas com inicializador de array definido nos names, então até aí tudo bem.

Os dados chegaram ao PHP na variável GET e ficaram dessa forma

```
Array
(
    [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18
            [1] => 19
            [2] => 110
        )
)
```

Temos alguns problemas no foreach que você fez, são eles:

- Você definiu um echo pra algo relacionado a semana na variável $key dentro do foreach, mas como pode ver na ilustração acima, as chaves do array não correspondem a nenhuma semana. Elas são geradas de forma crescente inciando a partir do 0, a menos que mude isso.
- Você criou um segundo foreach acoplado ao primeiro, mas a variável $value correspondente ao primeiro foreach, não é um array, não no seu caso.

Pra funcionar, você deve fazer dessa forma (além de corrigir a questão da semana, isso depende do que você está querendo fazer)

```
$formValues = isset($_GET['values']) ? $_GET['values'] : null;

if (!empty($formValues)) {
    foreach ($formValues as $key => $value) {
        echo "Semana {$key}<br>{$value}<br>";
    }
}
```

## Armazenando dados

Você disse que seu sistema tem vários formulários que constituem em etapas onde o visitante vai preenchendo os dados e avançando, então pra poder usar os dados dos primeiros formulário no futuro, você deve armazená-los de alguma forma.

São muitas e muitas as formas de se fazer isso, tudo depende do seu sistema, recursos e o quão seguro ele precisa ser.

Duas das formas mais comuns e simples são:

- É possível armazenar os dados no banco de dados, resgatando-os através da ID de sessão do usuário (caso tenha um sistema de login e ele esteja logado) ou através de um identificador de sessão criado por você mesmo. Um cookie com um ID único, por exemplo (no caso de querer usar cookies, lembre-se de fazer todas as validações necessárias para deixar o sistema seguro, por exemplo, pra acessar os dados de uma determinada sessão, além de ter que ter o cookie com o ID da sessão, o cliente também deve ter o mesmo IP usado para criar a sessão. É bom colocar também um tempo de validade para os dados).
- É possível armazenar os dados usando apenas o PHP por meio de sessions ou cookies, o que dependendo do sistema, não é tão recomendado, porém, é a forma mais simples de se fazer.

Irei dar um exemplo usando apenas cookies, mas é praticamente a mesma coisa pra sessions. No caso do armazenamento via banco de dados, é só seguir a lógica que eu dei acima.

```
$formValues = isset($_GET['values']) ? $_GET['values'] : null;

if (!empty($formValues)) {
    $formValues = http_build_query($formValues);
}

setcookie('primeira_etapa', $formValues, (time() + (30 * 60))); //30 minutos de validade
```

Será montado um cookie chamado primeira_etapa com valor `0=18&1=19&2=110`

Para acessar o conteúdo do cookie posteriormente use `$_COOKIE['primeira_etapa']` e lembre-se que ele só estará disponível no próximo reload do site.

## Leituras recomendadas

[Função print_r](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print-r.php)
[Operador Ternário](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/operador-ternario)
[Foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)
[Função http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.http-build-query.php)
[Trabalhando com cookies no PHP](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/trabalhando-com-cookies-no-php)